# Hidden expression not returning correct data type - ssrs

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a parameter which is set as an integer (@Period) which is currently set to 3 and only want columns (Periods 1-12) in my tablix to show if they are less than the @Period, so i have used the visibility expression for column "1": 
= iif( 1 < Parameters!Period.Value, "False", "True" ).

My Report runs but shows an error on the particular page saying: 
An error occurred during local report processing. 
The hidden expression used in Tablix18 returned a data type that is not valid.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is returning a String with "True" or "False".

Remove the quotes and it will return the Boolean **True** or **False**.